# Why integrate using dy instead of dx using shell method?

Tags: calculus

Find the volume of the solid generated by revolving the region in the 1st quadrant bounded by $y=x^3$ and $y=4x$ about $b$. The line $y=8$.

Why integrate using $dy$ instead of $dx$ using shell method?

Comment: You should draw a picture of the areas you are stacking together to form the volume. Then you'll see what you're integrating with respect to, and whatnot.

Comment: the radius of the shell is 8-y. Shouldn't it be 8-x because we find the distance from y=8 to the x-axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using shells, each element is a cylindrical shell centered on the axis.  The height of the shell is parallel to the axis.  As the axis is parallel to $y$, the height of the shell is the range in $y$ at a given radius and the thickness of the shell (which is small) is $dx$

Answering your comment on the question, the radius is the distance from the line $y=8$.  If the point is $(a,b)$, the distance from $y=8$ is $|b-8|$, so the radius should be $|y-8|$

Comment: The height is the distance in $y$ between the two curves at each $x$.  One curve is $y=4x$, which is the same as $x=y/4$.  The other is $y=x^3$, which is the same as $x=y^{1/3}$.  You choose the order to subtract to give a positive result.  In this case, if $x$ is just a little greater than zero, $x^{1/3} \gt x/4$  The region of interest continues until $x^{1/3}=x/4$ or $x^3=4x$